# Execute T-SQL-Scripts with JAVA and MS-SQL-Server

Tags: java, sql-server, t-sql, execute

i have a problem:

if have a T-SQL script like this one:

```
  IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.sysobjects WHERE id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[NDParamEmpfänger]'))
    BEGIN
        CREATE TABLE [dbo].[NDParamEmpfänger]
        (
            Id int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
            EmpfängerName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
            EmpfängerAdresse varchar(255) NOT NULL,
            EmpfängerArt tinyint NOT NULL,
            QuittierungsTimeOut smallint NOT NULL,
            ZustellungsTimeOut smallint NOT NULL,
            Format varchar(2000) NOT NULL,
            Wiederholungen tinyint  NOT NULL
        )
    END
    GO
```

I read in this script-file with a little Class called ScriptRunner [(http://pastebin.com/f10584951)](http://pastebin.com/f10584951). ScriptRunner separates the whole Script by "GO".

Everthing is fine, the single "batches" separated by "GO" in my .sql-Script are send to the MS-SQL-Server. (I checked it with the Profiler), BUT nothing happens.

The table(s) are not created.

When i run the script in SQL-Management-Studio it works fine.

What is my problem?

Comment: There is always a bad idea. Database design using special characters. Not all programs sending data to the server correctly. Try it without 'ä' use 'ae'.

Comment: No, thats not the problem. I tried it, but no change :(